# double-submit issue in browsers - Bootstrap + Django

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap, double-submit-problem

I have Bootstrap modal window for updating data everytime I close it, I face the so-called double-submission problem. That is, if I press F5, a message pops up telling me that I'm going to submit the same data for the second time and it inserts records into my table if I press ok. Moreover, if I try to open the modal window for the second time, it is rendered incorrectly ! Does it have anything to do with Django somehow ?

The modal window:

```
<form class="modal fade" id="openTaskWindow" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg form-horizontal" role="form">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Новая задача</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body" style="font-size: smaller">
        {{ createTask_form.as_p}}   
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">    
        <input class="btn btn-default btn-sm" type="submit" value="Сохранить"/>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

The button that calls the window:

```
<div><button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#openTaskWindow" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">Launch my modal</button></div>
```

The view (that is called when submit button of the modal window is pressed):

```
def createTask(request):
    taskTable = Tasks.objects.all()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        task_form = TaskForm(request.POST)

        if task_form.is_valid():
            temp_form = task_form.save(commit=False)
            temp_form.is_important = 0 
            temp_form.save()
            return render_to_response('task_management/task_list.html',{'createTask_form':temp_form, 'taskTable': taskTable},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    else:
        task_form = TaskForm()
    return render_to_response('task_management/task_list.html',{'createTask_form':task_form, 'taskTable': taskTable, 'task_id':''},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

After reading discussions of the community, I tried to do this:

```
$('#openTaskWindow').submit(function() {
        location.href = location.href;
    });
```

but it did not help. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this has not much to do with Django. The browser cache the post request for re-submission. The easiest way to prevent this is to return `HttpResponseRedirect` when for is valid.

So instead

```
if task_form.is_valid():
    temp_form = task_form.save(commit=False)
    temp_form.is_important = 0 
    temp_form.save()
    return render_to_response('task_management/task_list.html',{'createTask_form':temp_form, 'taskTable': taskTable},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Try to do

```
if task_form.is_valid():
    temp_form = task_form.save(commit=False)
    temp_form.is_important = 0 
    temp_form.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect('your_url')
```

And if you need to pass some extra arguments to the view you can accomplish that through query string or session based cache. And you don't need your Javascript hack.

Comment: "you can accomplish that through query string" - can you be kind enough to provide me with sample code on how to pass the arguments? I am newbie to Django :) Thank you so much for your answer. I've spent entire day on this

Comment: If you do `return HttpResponseRedirect('your_url?foo=bar')` then inside your view `foo` can be accessed by `request.GET.get('foo')`. That means it was send as a GET parameter or in other words as a part of query string.